# Воровство домена.

Tags: права, домен

Есть домен, который был зарегистрирован в сторонней конторе naunet.ru.

Допустим:
**XXX.ru**

```
domain:        XXX.RU
nserver:       ns1..net.
nserver:       ns2..net.
state:         REGISTERED, DELEGATED, UNVERIFIED
person:        Private Person
registrar:     NAUNET-REG-RIPN
admin-contact: https://client.naunet.ru/c/whoiscontact
created:       
paid-till:     
source:        TCI
```

Проблема:
Есть девушка, у которой есть компания( её отца) которой нужен этот домен.
Домен и хостинг ей делал её муж. С мужем она развелась, и домен он возвращать отказался.
Она ничего в этом не понимает.
Домен, хостинг, сайт как бы принадлежат ей, муж просто помогал. Но необходимо найти возможность получить туда доступ.

- Муж при регистрации домена, запрашивал паспортные данные отца девушки, но она не уверена, что эти данные указаны у компании регистратора naunet.ru. (в whois есть запись UNVERIFIED).

1) Можно ли узнать данные 
"person:        Private Person"

У компании naunet.ru указано
"К сожалению, в соответствии с правилами регистрации доменных имен в зонах RU и РФ мы не имеем права раскрывать этот адрес третьим лицам"

2) Если выясниться, что в качестве Private Person указан не бывший муж, а отец девушки, то можно ли будет приехать с этим отцом, верифицировать данные, и получить логин с паролем от naunet.ru.

3) На самом сайте, есть контактные данные фирмы девушки(телефоны), можно ли как то заверить эти данные у нотариуса? Чтобы доказать, что домен принадлежал сайту?

4) Что еще можно предпринять?

Comment: @manking прям сюжет, достойный мексиканского сериала. А вообще этот вопрос вряд ли по адресу, поскольку затрагивает правовые аспекты регулирования доменных имён. Вероятно, по вопросам нотариального заверения данных имеет смысл обратиться к юристу

Comment: @manking, а что отвечают в этом `naunet.ru` на самый простой "заход":

     забыл логин и пароль, что делать?

Comment: Если название компании совпадает с доменным именем (по написанию, звучанию и т.д.), то можно отсудить права на имя (но это я считаю крайняя мера)

Comment: Из мой практики:

 1. Нет
 2. 99%, что да
 3. 99%, что нет. Сайт и домен - разные вещи. И принадлежать могут разным лицам.
 4. Подожать, пока истечет проплата за домен и он будет разделегирован. И надеяться, что а) муж на него забьет, б) домен по-быстрому не попадет на аукцион. И зарегистрировать его по-новой.

По поводу переписки: многие регистраторы/хостеры отвечают на запросы по доменным именам, только если письмо отправлено с почтового ящика, указанного при регистрации домена.

Comment: 1) А если ОТЕЦ девушки приедет с паспортом в эту компанию и спросит,
"Указаны ли мои паспортные данные в качестве администратора этого домена?" 
То ему могут ответить? Или вообще никак не ответят?


2) Я слышал, что если у компании зарегистрирован товарный знак и он полностью совпадает с названием домена, то шансов сохранить домен у ПАРНЯ будет очень мало через суд?
Домен зарегистрирован после регистрации товарного знака. Я это давно читал в новостях nic.ru. Это может относится к зоне .ru или только .рф?

Comment: > 2) Я слышал, что если у компании зарегистрирован товарный знак и он полностью совпадает с названием домена, то шансов сохранить домен у ПАРНЯ будет очень мало через суд

Недавно на хабре проходила новость: человек создал сайт 02.ru, через 2 года создалась фирма одва, и вот недавно эта фирма отсудила у человека это имя.

Comment: > человек создал сайт 02.ru, через 2
> года создалась фирма одва, и вот
> недавно эта фирма отсудила у человека
> это имя.

Ну это уже беспределом попахивает. Неужели тот человек на которого был зарегистрирован сайт 02.ru не смог отстоять свое право? У него преимущество по датам было явное...

Comment: @IntegralAL, Вы из какой страны? Тут 02 - это менты.

Comment: 02.ru - это Правоохранительный портал, Сообщество правоохранительных органов России.. может поэтому.. лол

Comment: o2, а не 02...

Comment: А какие есть варианты выяснить что указано в whois: 

"person: Private Person"

Есть ли организация которая стоит над naunet.ru, например nic.ru или что то еще, куда можно приехать с паспортными данными и выяснить что указано в whois? Потому что девушка сказала, что звонила в naunet.ru и там ей сказали что никакой информации по домену не дадут, нужно писать из внутреннего кабинета.

Comment: >Ну это уже беспределом попахивает

так это Россия, чему удивляться? Здесь и не такие бизнесы отжимались

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет прямого отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нет, просто так их узнать нельзя, только по запросу из правохранительных органов.
2. Да можно, даже если анкета заполнена не до конца правильно.
3. Нет, домен может принадлежать одному лицу, а сайт другому.
4. Нужно позвонить в компанию, обрисовать ситуацию, которую вы здесь описали, далее попросить менеджера назвать первую букву фамилии или попробовать назвать ему возможные фамилии: отца и/или бывшего мужа, если менеджер пойдет на встречу то всё получится.

И да, это не воровство домена, а обычная человеческая глупость. Когда ничего не понимающая женщина берется зарегистрировать домен для своего отца, прибегнув к помощи мужа.